# SharedPreferences - load and clear it on another activity

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

Can anyone see what I have done wrong :( ?

I am trying to create an activity with a button and that button will perform a clear saved data in sharedpreferences on other activity.

This is the clear data activity

```
public class Clear_data extends Activity {

public Button bt1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cdata);

    LoadPreferences();

    bt1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cData);


    bt1.setOnClickListener(remove_data);
}

private void LoadPreferences(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Test.SharedP, MODE_PRIVATE);
    String strSaved1 = sharedPreferences.getString("SP1", "");

   }

View.OnClickListener remove_data = new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Test.SharedP, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
    finish();
    finish();
}   
};
```

}

and this is the main activity which i am trying to clear the data from

```
public class Test extends Activity {
public TextView tv3, tv5;
public EditText et1, et2;
public Button b1, b2, b3, b4 ;
public ImageView img1, img2;
public static String SharedP = "MyPrefsFile"; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

LoadPreferences();
}

private void SavePreferences(String key, String value){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Test.SharedP, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
   }

private void LoadPreferences(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Test.SharedP, MODE_PRIVATE);
    String strSaved1 = sharedPreferences.getString("SP1", "");
    tv5.setText(strSaved1);
   }
View.OnClickListener convert_handlermtok = new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (et1.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(Test.this, "put sommat in then you idiot!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else { 
        // Conversion is here
        // Defining the value and method to display the result
        int Amount = (int) Float.parseFloat(et1.getText().toString());
        int exchanged = (int) (Amount * 1.609344) ; 
        String result = String.valueOf(exchanged);
        Toast.makeText(Test.this, "Converted Speed " + (et1.getText().toString()) + 
        " Mph = " + result + " Kph", 
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  

        SavePreferences("SP1", et1.getText().toString() + 
                " Mph = " + result + " Kph");
        LoadPreferences();
    }
    }
};
```

Comment: can you please tell, what is the problem?

Comment: the problem is the Clear_data Activity doesn't do anything when I've pressed the clear data button. It didn't clear the data saved on the Test Activity.

Comment: it should be clearing the preferences. `It does not do anything` you said this after seeing `tv5` value? call `LoadPreferences()` in `onResume` methode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to call another activity to clear your sharedpreference. Doing it from the current activity should be sufficient.

btw. you can make your sharedPreference a property of the class instead of opening it every time you need it.